# Name of non-hypotenuse side

Tags: trigonometry, notation

From school trigonometry (and SohCahToa) the non-hypotenuse sides of a right triangle are the *opposite* and *adjacent* with respect to a given angle, but what would one call those sides when there is no given angle?  I've heard *legs*, but that seems unsatisfactory.  Are there other names?

Comment: "Legs" is the only term that I have ever heard.  What is unsatisfactory about that?

Comment: [cathetus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cathetus). You can find it in the Wiki's entry on [Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#By_internal_angles).

Comment: @XanderHenderson, seems a bit childish, and they don't look like legs!

Comment: I had not seen "cathetus" until some people posted with that term here. It's always been "leg" to me, since my (U.S.) high school geometry days ... an unspecified number of decades ago. I'll note that "isosceles" means "equal leg", so calling triangle sides "legs" is a (ahem) long-standing tradition.

Comment: @Blue, well played and/or [groan]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common term used is [*legs*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Triangle.html), but as pointed out by others there is also the rarer term [*catheti*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cathetus.html).

In German, there are actually specific names for the adjacent and opposite sides: *Ankathete* and *Gegenkathete* respectively.

Comment: German is such a sensible language :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is a specific, Greek-derived name (which I have never heard used in English) for the two short sides of a right-angled triangle. It is [*cathetus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathetus). It's much more common to just refer to them as "legs".

The Greek-derived term is used in other languages, though. For instance, in Norwegian, my native language, "katet" is ubiquitous.

Comment: Actually, this is Latin (derived from Greek).

Comment: @Bernard I did say Greek-derived, not Greek.

Answer (score 1):

They are called *legs* or *catheti*. I know that they called "Kathete" in german and this is the usual term, but it seems the term "cathetus" is rarely used in english.